# HttpRequest POST method timeout when using proxy

Tags: c#, post, proxy, timeout, httprequest

the following is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = timeout;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://" + proxyUsed + "/", true);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "";

foreach (string[] p in parameter)
{
    if (postData != "")
        postData += "&";
    postData += string.Format("{0}={1}", p[0], p[1]);
}
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();
}

using (WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        httpLink = myResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
        sr.Close();
    }
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

I have encountered a problem that when makeing a POST http request to a Webpage. When I use direct connection it works fine. But if I use proxy, it throw a timeout exception. However, if I set the postData to be empty, it works fine even I am using proxy.
What's the most likely reason for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a huge amount of information to go on, do you have access to the proxy servers logs?

If you inspect the return variables are you getting a 405 error? This would indicate that the proxy does not support POST processing.

In terms of debugging, what I would do is [setup fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to be your proxy (or use it transparently) then you can view the traffic going in and out of your box and analyse the data to see if there's any abnormalities in the request/response.

Comment: I believe that the proxy support POST processing since it can successful get the response from other website by POST

Comment: I think setting up fiddler is your best option then, that way you can see the incoming/outgoing data responses.

Comment: Ah..I don't know how to set up the fiddler to the VS program, I　have tried to focus the program only or all processes, but I didn't see anything.

Comment: Install fiddler, set the fiddler port to 8888, in fiddler set a forwarding proxy to your external proxy and point your code proxy at localhost:8888.

Comment: Sorry, how can I set a forwarding proxy in fiddler? Is that put the code oSession.oRequest["Proxy-Authorization"] = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx";? I have tried it but seems not this way

Comment: The easiest way is probably just to let fiddler hook into winsock. It does this by default I believe, so in fiddler just start a capture session and it should pick up the details automatically without editing settings. If that doesn't work then you set it using request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://" + proxyUsed + "/", true);